# Number of cells of raster under a condition

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a binary raster file and I want to count the number of pixels with value one. How do I do that with R?

Comment: not clear why this was closed. "Not about programming" seems like a poor fit to this question?

Answer (score 4):

Ben Bolker's solution, but then with `terra` (the replacement for `raster`)

```
set.seed(101)
library(terra)
r <- rast(matrix(sample(0:1,size=10000,replace=TRUE),100))
global(r, sum)
#       sum
#lyr.1 4984
```

To count the number of `1`s in non-binary rasters, and considering `NA`s, I would prefer

```
global(r==1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

over

```
global(r, function(x) sum(x==1, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Because the former also works on very large rasters, as "sum" is a known function that can be computed in chunks.

Answer (score 2):

There may well be a more efficient way to do this, but:

```r
set.seed(101)
library(raster)
r <- raster(matrix(sample(0:1,size=10000,replace=TRUE),100))
cellStats(r,function(x,...) sum(x==1))  ## 4984
```

Actually, if this is a *binary* raster, `cellStats(r, sum)` works just as well (and probably quicker?)