# Counting pixels of same value in R

Tags: r, pixel, counting, calculation, area

I need help with counting pixels of the same value in R. I'm doing a master thesis and part of it is calculating the NDWI of an area before and after floods so I can calculate the surface under water. From the results of NDWI after the flood values that are above 0 are under water and those under 0 are not. So I'm kinda stuck here bcs I can't figure out how to calculate all pixels above value 0.

Comment: What format is your data in, and do you have any example data we can use to test and verify possible solutions? It's going to be very hard to give you any coding solutions to the problem without this.

Comment: Are you using a workflow like [Flood Hazard Mapping India](https://rpubs.com/delViento/flood_india_ndwi)?

Comment: Its all raster data because i also use it in ArcMap.  This is a short example: library(raster)
b2 <- raster("C:\\Users\\filip\\Documents\\R\\Vjezba\\Poslije\\LC08_L1TP_188029_20140522_20200911_02_T1_B2.TIF")
plot(b2)
After plotting i need to calculate, for example, how many pixels are in the range 40000-50000. You can use any jpg or tif file to try it out. Btw sorry idk how to write code here properly like others so it has that gray box.

Comment: @Chris Yeah it's pretty much it, but without some parts. I have that one step where I gotta calculate pixels that are under water and can't find solution yet :)

Comment: If you put three (3) ` backtics, at the start of your code, then three ` to terminate, you achieve the `gray box` effect. The above reference starts with discussion of 'false positives', certainly useful to your purposes. Perhaps share your bounding box for sentinal data you're using.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jeyom3jfbdoxfkv/AADUCZnl_OgZMDh59Q0h6Emca?dl=0    There's .tif image with calculated NDWI. So from that image, i need to calculate how many pixels are there with values from 0 up to the max value.   @Chris

Comment: While you've probably read this [Effectiveness of Sent1 Sent2 for Flood Detection](https://nhess.copernicus.org/preprints/nhess-2022-63/), and see closed [SOF Hijmans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442419/number-of-cells-of-raster-under-a-condition) (any Hijmans answer you should follow). What is your thesis and does it involve band combinations?

Comment: Yeah, I came across that but since I'm doing my thesis with Landsat data I didn't go through it all. Well, my thesis isn't fully determined, but it's basically to determine how many km^2 was flooded by using NDWI before and after flood. Even though my mentor didn't say that I'm also trying to do the same thing with ArcMap so I can compare results between R and ArcMap. Also, I've come across software like Global Mapper so maybe ill try to make 3D visualization of the flood in that area if I figure out how to do it :) I don't think it will involve some band combinations besides calculating NDWI.

Answer (score 0):

Using your dropbox data:

```
library(terra)
ndwi <- rast('Clip_ndwi_poslije1.tif')
ndwi_vec <- values(ndwi, mat = FALSE)
> length(which(ndwi_vec > 0))
[1] 21157
> length(which(ndwi_vec <= 0))
[1] 13217
> dim(ndwi)[1]
[1] 220
> dim(ndwi)[1]*dim(ndwi)[2]
[1] 58300
> sum(length(which(ndwi_vec > 0)), length(which(ndwi_vec <= 0)))
[1] 34374
> table(is.na(ndwi[])) #  see below

FALSE  TRUE 
34374 23926
```

Table approach is from [SOF-GIS ?s](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347333/check-for-nas-in-rasterlayer-and-plot-them-in-different-colour), and get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Your data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast("Clip_ndwi_poslije1.tif")
```

You could count the cells with values that are larger than zero (or not) like this:

```
freq(r > 0)
#     layer value count
#[1,]     1     0 13217
#[2,]     1     1 21157
```

`TRUE == 1`, so you have 21,157 cells with a value larger than zero.

But to accurately compute the area covered by these cells, you need to first get the area of each cell:

```
a <- cellSize(r)
```

And then sum these areas

```
b <- ifel(r > 0, a, NA)
# or the equivalent
# b <- mask(a, r>0, maskvalue=0)

global(b, "sum", na.rm=TRUE)
#            sum
#ndwiii 19013036
```

In this case, that is similar to (incorrectly) assuming that the *nominal* spatial resolution is valid for each grid cell.

```
global(r > 0, "sum", na.rm=TRUE) * prod(res(r))
#             sum
#ndwiii 19041300
```

Comment: Thanks, tried both solutions and both are great. :)